# adding an exam booking detail to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how to add an exam booking audit trail to the database, where we can determine when and who has uploaded exam results

Answer (score 1):

You just create a table and then write a class that inserts values into your table. Easy as that.

P.S. ask a vague question and you will get a vague answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement data modification auditing using triggers to write user action info of interest to a separate table or tables [as described here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx).